# merge two array objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

---

I've try to merge two array but it become like this image..

[image]

I want it when merged it become like this exaple

```
{0: {…}, storedArr: Array(2)}
0:
address: "ifanio de los Santos Ave, Mandaluyong, 1550 Metro Manila, Philippines"
addressNick: "test1"
latitude: 14.5724682
longitude: 121.0470239
remarks: "No.12"

1:
address: "ifanio de los Santos Ave, Mandaluyong, 1550 Metro Manila, Philippines"
latitude: 14.5724682
longitude: 121.0470239
remarks: "No.12"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(2)
__proto__: Obj
```

This is my example code as your reference

```
this.storage.get('storedAdd').then((addrr)=>{
      let storedArr = [];
      console.log(val)
        storedArr.push({
          address: val.address[0],
          addressNick: val.addressNickName,
          remarks: val.remarks,
          latitude: val.latitude,
         longitude: val.longitude
        });
        console.log(storedArr)
        console.log(addrr)
       this.storage.set('storedAdd', {...storedArr,...addrr});
      console.log({storedArr,...addrr})
      const datatransf = {...storedArr,...addrr}
      console.log(datatransf)
    this.packageAdd$.next(datatransf);
           
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to spread an array into an object here. This will give you an array inside the object under `0` index.

```
this.storage.set('storedAdd', {...storedArr,...addrr});
```

Are you sure this is what you wanted? Maybe it should be like this:

```
this.storage.set('storedAdd', [...storedArr,...addrr]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are spreading your arrays into object `{ ...arr1, ...arr2 }` instead of array `[ ...arr1, ...arr2 ]`

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var arr2 = ['d', 'e']

var merged = [...arr1, ...arr2]

console.log(merged)
```